# DISABLE SQLSERVER VSS backups

Tags: sql-server, backup

I have some automated backups that i want to disable. but i do not know how to do it. Apparently these are done via Volume Shadow copy Service  .

Can anyone tell how to get rid of these backups ?

[image]

Comment: You likely have some third party software taking backups.  Why do you want to delete this?

Comment: I want to have backup plan using the GUI of SQL SERVER and have full control of all backups.

Comment: Is it SQL SERVER WRITER the service responsible for this Shadow backups ?

Comment: No they are not responsible for backup but these services allow third party backup tools  as a *medium* to connect to SQL Server and perform backup. So yes if you disable `SQL Server VSS writer service` these backups will fail.

Comment: Another disatvantage of these backups is that i get each time  I/O Forozen  which is very bad if someone queries the DB .

Comment: This is nature of how VSS backups works, they first freeze IO to get consistent view on files and then take backup. The whole explanation is documented in [Understanding VDI VSS backups](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2009/04/28/informational-shedding-light-on-vss-vdi-backups-in-sql-server.aspx)

Comment: So is it bad to disable this middle service ? or is there any tool to see which 3rd party is running these backups ?

Comment: I replied to my question on another related topic [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/120472/db-backups-not-secheduled)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to do a trace or Extended Event session to determine what application is attempting the backups. Be sure to include the client hostname and application name, those two generally help indicate what is taking the backup. The client hostname will most always show the local machine name, which if that is the case look at what is installed on the server.

Some examples of 3rd products that will use VSS:

- Symantec NetBackup SQL Agent
- Symantec Backup Exec ( I believe does this now as well)
- VMWare/Hyper-V (both products have options to along with snapshot of server to also do database)

Comment: I will try to find what is doing shadow backups . But can i just kill SQLWRITER service and all is ok ?

Comment: I found that i have scheduled some backups of the C:\ drive folders .